# on editing a row using editGridRow function of Jqgrid, it not only edits data but also changes uneditable id column value to selrowid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, save, edit

I am creating a jqgrid which is being populated by data from a jsp. It has 3 columns Name, Description and an uneditable column Id. I have 5 buttons : New, Modify, Delete, Ok and Cancel on the page.I want to let the user to edit/add data locally to jqgrid via a popup form and on click of save it adds to db.

```
$("#template-list").jqGrid
  ({ 
        url:'getTemplateCategories.jsp?TrUserId=122',
        datatype: 'xml', 
        mtype: 'post',
        colNames:['Name','Description','id','SaveAs'],
        colModel :[
                    {name:'Name',index:'Name', width:300, align:'left', sortable:false,xmlmap:"catName", editable:true},
                    {name:'Description',index:'Description', width:300, align:'left', sortable:false,xmlmap:"catDescription", editable:true},
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:0, align:'left', sortable:false,xmlmap:"catId" , hidden: false},
                    {name:'SaveAs', index:'SaveAs', width:0, align:'left', sortable:false, hidden: false}
                   ],
        xmlReader: { 
                     root:"Categories", 
                     row:"item",                  
                     repeatitems:false                
                   },
        height : '461',
        scrollOffset:"0",
        hidegrid: "No",
        closeAfterAdd : true,   
        closeAfterEdit : true,    
        border: '2',
        pager: '#template-pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        minheight: '190',
        width: '600',
        autoheight: true,
        mtype:'POST',
        forceFit : true,    
        align:'left',   
        emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
        rowNum:'20',
        paging: true,
        editurl: 'TemplateCategoryWebView.jsp',
        cellsubmit:'clientArray',               
        loadonce : true  
   });
```

I am using the following code to add / edit a row on button click after row selection :

```
 function add()
{   
    $("#template-list").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{width:400,height:200,reloadAfterSubmit:false,closeAfterAdd:true});
}
function modify()
{   
    var selRowId = $('#template-list').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    var rowid =  $('#template-list').jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'id') ;
    var rowData = $("#template-list").jqGrid('getRowData',rowid);
    if( selRowId)
    {
        $('#template-list').jqGrid('editGridRow',selRowId,{width:400,height:200,reloadAfterSubmit:false,closeAfterEdit:true});
        alert("selRowId  :  "+selRowId+"    rowid : "+rowid);
        EditCats=EditCats.concat(rowid) ;   

    }   
    else
    {
        alert("Please select a row");
    }
}
```

Now when I edit a particular row, it opens that record and allows user to edit name and description values and when i click the submit button it not only saves edited values  locally in the jqgrid but also changes the "id" column value to value of "selRowId". Can someone please explain what is going on as I am at my wits end trying to fix this. I want this functionality to behave exactly as I mentioned and not by any other alternative method like inline editing because this is a migration project and they want to retain the way the functionality was working earlier(ie using popup screens) to reduce customer learning curve.I have been searching for a solution to this problem since quite some time but have not got one.

It also tried passing the id value in editGridRow but its of no use. Please help.

Thanks,
Anita

Comment: Could you change `id` in `colModel` (`name:'id',index:'id'`) to some other name and repeat the same test? For example you can use `name:'catId'` instead of `name:'id',index:'id'`. The problem is that the name `id` will be used internally during editing of data.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you for your reply. changed the colModel values and now it works fine for edit but now on adding a new row, the id is blank when it should be jqg1.

Comment: You should use `reloadAfterSubmit: true` option at least for Add form. If you don't use that you have to return the new value of `id` (`catId`) in the server response of `editurl: 'TemplateCategoryWebView.jsp'`. If the response will be **not wrap in XML** then jaGrid will modify rowid for you. If you want to display the id to the user (in `catId` column) or is the server response is not new id only (for example XML wrapped) then you have to use `afterSubmit` callback of form editing. So my recommendation is: use `reloadAfterSubmit: true` for Add at least for the begging.

Comment: @oleg sorry for the late reply but that did not work either

Comment: @Anita, can I ask you something on this same issue...if this issue is resolved??

Comment: @Jaikrat yes I have posted the working code for your reference.

Comment: Thanks @Anita. But I am no more facing this issue. Resolved long back but thanks for posting answer.. Someone else might get benifited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $("#template-list").jqGrid
  ({ 
        url:"getTemplateCategories.jsp?TrUserId=<%=TrUserId%>",
        datatype: 'xml', 
        mtype: 'post',
        colNames:['Name','Description','Id'],
        colModel :[
                    {name:'Name',index:'Name', width:$(window).width()/2, align:'left', sortable:false,xmlmap:"catName", editable:true},
                    {name:'Description',index:'Description',  width:$(window).width()/2, align:'left', sortable:false,xmlmap:"catDescription", editable:true},
                    {name:'Ids',index:'Ids', width:0, align:'left', sortable:false,xmlmap:"catId" , hidden: true},
                    ],
        xmlReader: { 
                     root:"Categories", 
                     row:"item",                  
                     repeatitems:false                
                   },
        height: $(window).height()-110,        
        width: $(window).width() - 11,
        autowidth: false,
        autoheight: false,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        scrollOffset:"0",
        forceFit : true,
        hidegrid: "No",
        closeAfterAdd : true,   
        closeAfterEdit : true,    
        border: '2',
        pager: '#template-pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        mtype:'POST',           
        align:'left',               
        rownumbers : true,
        emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
        rowNum:'20',
        paging: true,
        editurl: 'TemplateCategoryWebView.jsp',
        cellsubmit:'clientArray',
        loadonce : true

   });
```